# Jade gives empty page(No error)

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm new to nodejs and jade and following a small blog tutorial. I got the jade page working properly without extending layout. The moment I extend layout in my index.jade the page goes blank. Any idea what's going on here?

Layout.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

index.jade (without the `extends layout`)

```
h1= locals.title
#articles
    - each article in locals.articles
        div.article
            div.created_at= article.created_at
            div.title
                a(href="/blog/"+article._id)!= article.title
            div.body= article.body
```

And the rendering in app.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs) {
        res.render('index.jade', { locals: {
                title: "Blog",
                articles: docs
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: try checking if your indentation is correct

Comment: There are no errors. SO it must be. And without extending the layout it works like a charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out by not using the extend alone but the block aswell (see [layout/block documentation)](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#block-append--prepend)

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= locals.title
```

Instead of

```
extends layout
h1= locals.title
```